# VB Script in Access Variable not found

Tags: forms, vba, ms-access-2007

So I was advised that I could create some copy replace functionality to this form.

Here is my coding attempt in VB:

First I connect to DB using DAO. Then I use a SELECT statement that has been verified to pull the last record inserted into the DB. Then I try to refill the controls with the values from the query but I am getting reference errors.

```
Private Sub AutoFill_Click()
Dim db As DAO.Database, rs As DAO.Recordset
Dim strSQL As String

Set db = CurrentDb()
strSQL = "SELECT DISTINCTROW  TOP 1 CPOrders.Cust, Customer.NAME, CPOrders.CP_Ref, CPOrders.Slsman, CPOrders.Date_opn, CPOrders.CPSmall, CPOrders.InvIssu, CPOrders.InvNo, CPOrders.InvDate, CPOrders.DueDate, CPOrders.ETADate, CPOrders.Closed, CPOrders.BuyerRef, CPOrders.ToCity, CPOrders.ToState, CPOrders.ToCtry, CPOrders.ToPort, CPOrders.Supplier, CPOrders.Origin, CPOrders.Product, CPOrders.GradeType, CPOrders.NoUnits, CPOrders.Pkg, CPOrders.Qty, CPOrders.TotSale, CPOrders.TotCost, CPOrders.GrMargin, CPOrders.[Sale$/Unit], CPOrders.[Cost$/Unit], CPOrders.OceanCost, CPOrders.OceanNotes, CPOrders.BLadingDate, CPOrders.USAPort, CPOrders.FOBCost, CPOrders.FASExportVal, CPOrders.InlandFrt, CPOrders.CommodCode, CPOrders.Notes FROM Customer INNER JOIN CPOrders ON Customer.[CUST_#] = CPOrders.Cust ORDER BY CPOrders.CP_Ref desc;"
Set rs = db.OpenRecordset(strSQL, dbOpenDynaset, dbReadOnly)
rs.MoveFirst 

CP_Ref.ControlSource = rs!CP_Ref
Slsman.ControlSource = rs!Slsman
CPSmall.ControlSource = rs!CPSmall
InvIssu.ControlSource = rs!InvIssu
InvDate.ControlSource = rs!InvDate
DueDate.ControlSource = rs!DueDate
Closed.ControlSource = rs!Closed



rs.Close
db.Close
```

The control source reference picks up and autocompletes the word.

I would think that as it stands. although i'm not filling all the values with records from my SELECT statement that it would populate but instead i get things like `#NAME?` where the values should be. I also get a break in my code and it says "Invalid use of null"

Why? I appreciate your guys input and I can provider screenshots if necessary. I think this is involving the reference tie, but I'm not sure. Any help is much appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are using the field names from the SELECT statement as if they were variables.

```
CP_Ref.ControlSource = rs("CP_Ref")
Slsman.ControlSource = rs("Slsman")
CPSmall.ControlSource = rs("CPSmall")
InvIssu.ControlSource = rs("InvIssu")
InvDate.ControlSource = rs("InvDate")
DueDate.ControlSource = rs("DueDate")
Closed.ControlSource = rs("Closed")
```

When you have that worked out, tackle the *"Invalid use of null"* problem by first identifying any fields that could potentially be NULL and using something like

`SELECT Iif(IsNull([InvDate]), '', [InvDate]) As [InvDate], ...`

in the SELECT statement to pass across a minimum of an empty string rather than a NULL value.